# Populating GridView from JSON using Async Task

Tags: android

I am trying to populate my Grid View from JSON received from server. Then I need to populate gridview from the results obtained. Below is the activity file for populating grid view

```
public class OpenTableActivity extends Activity {

    String serUri, method;
    OpenTableAdapter op;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tableList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.open_table);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.opentableLinear);
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
                hideKeyboard(view);
                return false;
            }
        });
        getTables();
            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this));
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.table_home_btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(homeBtn);
    }

    public boolean getTables() {

        serUri = "tables.json";

        method = "get";
        WebServiceAsyncTask webServiceTask = new WebServiceAsyncTask(OpenTableActivity.this);
        webServiceTask.execute(serUri, method, this);

        return true;

    }

    public void WriteJsonArray(final JSONArray result, Context contextInstance) {


        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);


                String tabLabel = c.getString("tablabel");
                String tabStatus = c.getString("tabstatus");

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                map.put("table_name", tabLabel);
                map.put("table_status", tabStatus);

                tableList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Below is the Adapter class for Grid View

```
public class OpenTableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    String orderNumber;
    OpenTableActivity openInstance;
    String tableLabel;
    String tableStatus;
    //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> tablist = null;

    public OpenTableAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mContext = c;
        //tablist = tablelist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        openInstance = new OpenTableActivity();
        return openInstance.tableList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        openInstance = new OpenTableActivity();

        for (HashMap<String, String> map : openInstance.tableList)
            for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> mapEntry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = mapEntry.getKey();
                String value = mapEntry.getValue();
                btn.setText(key);
```

The tablelist is populated correctly in WriteJSONArray. Then control goes to adapter class from  `gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this));`. But it executes nothing there. I had put breakpoints to see the actual flow but it only comes to below method and nothing is executed thereafter.  There is no error in trace and it's not executing anything.

```
public OpenTableAdapter(Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = c;

}
```

I believe this is due to incorrect context passed when it comes from async task 'Post Execute' method. I tried with passing context but still same issue. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Try to clean build your project. Eclipse sometimes goes weird, and does not identify the methods included..

Comment: Thanks. I restarted eclipse and it got resolved. But now I have different issue. Updated my post with more information. Thanks again.

Comment: Post your Logcat here, and show exactly in which line you are getting exception..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized `GridView`

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

You have edited your post and say that you have gridview initialized so that's not a problem.

Initialize mInflater in the constructor of your BaseAdapter class.Also pass the hashmap to the construcotr and use the same in getview.

What your doing in getView is wrong `openInstance = new OpenTableActivity()` is wrong. You can start a Activity by calling `startActivity`.

```
   LayoutInflater mInflater;  
   public OpenTableAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    tablist = tablelist;
    }
```

In your `getView`

```
         ViewHolder holder; 

             if (convertView == null) { 
                 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.button, 
                         parent, false);
                 holder = new ViewHolder();  
                 holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);   
                convertView.setTag(holder); 
            } else { 
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
            } 

// use tablelist data to set the text to button using the position as index      

                 HashMap<String, String>> map = tablist.get(position)
                 // use the map to set the text to the button now. 
                    holder.btn.setText(key);
            return convertView; 
    }
```

Use a ViewHolder. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
   static class ViewHolder
   {
     Button btn;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, but its there. I accidentally deleted that while posting here. Edited my post. The error is there with that line too. Apologies for inconvenience.

Comment: do you have gridview with id grid in `open_table`? and post the stack trace

Comment: Yes its there. The issue is resolved now. But now facing original problem that the gridview is not being populated correctly. I have updated my post with more information on core issue. Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav there is a problem with getview

Comment: @Gaurav check the edit i have updated my post. it should work now all you need to do is get the value form the map and set it to button. i assume you have a layout button.xml and you have a button with id button in button.xml. I would suggest renaming the xml file to row.xml for clarity

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan. I tried as suggested and still same issue. I passed the Hashmap as gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this,tableList)); I checked with log statement and it seems that since tablelist is fetched from async task, adapter class is called even before results are fetched. I tried calling Adapter class in WriteJSON Array(which inturn is called from Post Execute) method but that too is giving null pointer exception when adapter class is called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35561/discussion-between-gaurav-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(this));
```

With

```
 gridview.setAdapter(new OpenTableAdapter(OpenTableActivity.this));
```

Comment: i don't see a problem with `this`. its no that he is calling setAdapter inside a button click listener.

Comment: I checked you code and I does not get any error. make the OpenTableAdapter class is subclass of OpenTableActivity class.